# Actualizar datos de un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy teniendo un problema y es que intento actualizar datos de un `RecyclerView` en un `Fragment` que carga información desde una consulta `PHP` en `MySQL`. Para ello, al clickear en un `item` del `RecyclerView` abro una nueva `Activity`, en esta cargo el dato del item del `RecyclerView` y lo actualizo. En mi `BD` veo la actualización, pero al volver a la `Activity` con el **listado**, este no ha hecho el cambio. Entiendo que para que esto funcione debería utilizar el `adaptador.notifyItemChanged(position);` lo que no entiendo es como aplicarlo de manera correcta en mi `Fragment`. Este es mi `Adaptador`:

```
public class RecyclerViewListaCartuchos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> mValues;
    Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(Context context, ArrayList<Cartuchos> values) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.vista_diseno_cartucho, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView idCartucho;
        public TextView modeloColor;
        public TextView tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod;
        public ImageView iv_cartucho_img;
        public View layout;
        Cartuchos item;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            cardView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            idCartucho = v.findViewById(R.id.idCartucho);
            modeloColor = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_modelo_color);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod);
            iv_cartucho_img = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_cartucho_img);

            switch (mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
                case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
                case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
                    cardView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    idCartucho.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    modeloColor.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void setData(Cartuchos item) {
            this.item = item;
            String dato = item.getModelo() + " " + item.getColor();
            String idC = String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho());
            String fec_us = "Última actualización: " + item.getFechaModificacion();
            idCartucho.setText(idC);
            modeloColor.setText(dato);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod.setText(fec_us);

            if(item.getModelo().contains("73")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sietetresn);
            }else if(item.getModelo().contains("90")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nueveceron);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();
            String idC = String.valueOf(idCartucho.getText());
            String cantidad = String.valueOf(item.getCantidad());
            //String mensaje = itemPosition + " / " + idC + "/Canti:" + cantidad;
            Intent abrirEditar = new Intent(mContext, Editar.class);
            abrirEditar.putExtra("idcartucho", String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho()));
            abrirEditar.putExtra("cantidad", String.valueOf(item.getCantidad()));
            abrirEditar.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(abrirEditar);
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es mi Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnCartuchos = findViewById(R.id.btnCartuchos);
        Button btnToners = findViewById(R.id.btnToners);

        if(ConexionInternet.estaConectado(MainActivity.this)){
            cargarFragmentCartuchos();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conéctate a una red.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        btnToners.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(ConexionInternet.estaConectado(MainActivity.this)){
                cargarFragmentToners();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conéctate a una red.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnCartuchos.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(ConexionInternet.estaConectado(MainActivity.this)){
                cargarFragmentCartuchos();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conéctate a una red.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void cargarFragmentCartuchos(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayoutListado, new ListadoCartuchos());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private void cargarFragmentToners() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayoutListado, new ListadoToners());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment fragmentActual = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayoutListado);
        if(fragmentActual instanceof ListadoToners){
            cargarFragmentCartuchos();
        }else if(fragmentActual instanceof ListadoCartuchos){
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es el `Fragment` donde cargo el `RecyclerView`:

```
public class ListadoCartuchos extends Fragment {
    TextView alerta;
    LinearLayout linearAlerta;
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> cartuchosArrayList;
    String infoCartuchos;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> arrayList;
    RecyclerViewListaCartuchos adaptador;

    public ListadoCartuchos() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listado, container, false);

        cartuchosArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        alerta = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAlertaCantidadCartuchos);
        linearAlerta = view.findViewById(R.id.linearAlertaCartucho);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCartuchos);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        cargarAlertaCartucho();
        listadoCartuchos();

        alerta.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (ConexionInternet.estaConectado(getContext())) {
                alertCartuchos();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Conéctate a una red.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void listadoCartuchos() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            int id = jsonObject1.getInt("idCartucho");
                            String modelo = jsonObject1.getString("modelo");
                            String color = jsonObject1.getString("color");
                            String fec = jsonObject1.getString("fechaModificacion");
                            int cantidad = jsonObject1.getInt("cantidad");
                            arrayList.add(new Cartuchos(id, modelo, color, fec, cantidad));
                        }
                        adaptador = new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(getActivity(), arrayList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("Listado", "listadoCartuchos: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void cargarAlertaCartucho(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",
                response -> {
                    try {
                        if(response.contains("Hay.")){
                            alerta.setText(getString(R.string.atencion));
                            response = response.replace("Hay.", "");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String modelo = jsonObject1.getString("modelo");
                                String color = jsonObject1.getString("color");
                                int cantidad = jsonObject1.getInt("cantidad");
                                cartuchosArrayList.add(new Cartuchos(modelo, color, cantidad));
                            }
                        } else {
                            linearAlerta.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("MainAcExc", "cargarAlertaCartucho: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void alertCartuchos(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("¡Atención!");
        for(int c = 0; c < cartuchosArrayList.size(); c++){
            infoCartuchos += cartuchosArrayList.get(c).getModelo() + " " + cartuchosArrayList.get(c).getColor() + " - Cantidad: " + cartuchosArrayList.get(c).getCantidad() + "\n";
            if(infoCartuchos.contains("null")){
                infoCartuchos = infoCartuchos.replace("null", "");
            }
        }
        alertDialog.setMessage("Se deben reponer los siguientes cartuchos: \n\n" + infoCartuchos);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cerrar", (dialog, which) -> { alertDialog.dismiss(); cartuchosArrayList.clear(); });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Al presionar el item del RecyclerView se abre, como ya mencioné, la actividad Editar:

```
public class Editar extends AppCompatActivity {
    String url;
    private EditText etEditarCantidad;
    private final String mensajeVacio = "No puede estar vacío ni el valor debe ser 0 (cero)";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar);
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        String idC = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idC);
        String cantidad = getIntent().getStringExtra("cantidad");

        etEditarCantidad = findViewById(R.id.etEditarCantidad);
        etEditarCantidad.setText(cantidad);
        Button btnEditar = findViewById(R.id.btnEditar);

        btnEditar.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString().length() == 0
                    || etEditarCantidad.getText().toString().equals("0")){
                Toast.makeText(Editar.this, mensajeVacio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                try{
                    if(ConexionInternet.estaConectado(Editar.this)){
                        editarCantidad(id);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Conéctate a una red.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error", "Editar error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void editarCantidad(int id){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString())){
            etEditarCantidad.setError("No puede estar vacío.");
            etEditarCantidad.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        final int cant = Integer.parseInt(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
            try {
                if (response.contains("Error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Lo sentimos, ha ocurrido un error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Modificado con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Editar.this.finish();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> Log.e("onErrorEdit", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage())){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                parametros.put("cantidad", String.valueOf(cant));
                parametros.put("id", String.valueOf(id));
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Editar.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

En esta actividad, recibo el valor de **cantidad** y lo modifico, al presionar **Guardar** este se modifica y se cierra la actividad volviendo al `RecyclerView` pero este no realiza el cambio de manera inmediata. Solo se refleja cuando reinicio la app. Estuve leyendo, en muchos caso se utiliza `adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();` pero esta misma recomienda ser más específica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A lo que pregunto, ¿Cómo debo hacerlo correctamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para llamar `notifyItemChanged(position)` lo puedes realizar desde el mismo adapter o fuera de la clase Adapter haciendo referencia a el Adapter, esta función realizará la actualización del elemento en cierta posición:

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentas que:

> pero al volver a la Activity con el listado, este no ha hecho el
> cambio. Entiendo que para que esto funcione debería utilizar el
> adaptador.notifyItemChanged(position);

aquí es importante que además de tu base de datos **el listado de tu `Adapter` contenga la información actualizada**, el elemento debe tener el valor actualizado de otra forma no podrá verse reflejado el cambio.

Puedes realizar un método en tu `adapter` el cual realice la actualización de los datos y que además actualice el `adapter`.

```
public void updateItem(Cartuchos item, int position)
{
    //Actualiza List.
    mValues.set(position, item);
    //Actualiza elemento en adapter.
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

de esta forma llamarías el método desde tu Fragment:

```
adaptador.updateItem(ObjetoActualizado, position)
```

Comment: Considerando el hecho de que en el Fragment solo tengo el listado, ¿Cómo obtengo la posicion del item seleccionadod del RecyclerView en el Fragment?

Comment: En tu RecyclerView implementas onClickListener entonces puedes obtener la posicion dentro de:  
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta

Comment: Excelente que fue de utilidad la respuesta , saludos

Answer (score -2):

Creo que esto podría servir si lo pones en tu activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

podrás encontrar información adicional acá:

[ciclo de vida de la actividad](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=es#onresume)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esto no resolve mi inquietud, pues esto: `adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();` sugiere ser más específico