# Problema al actualizar RecyclerView

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, recyclerview

Hace unos días hice esta pregunta [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488564/actualizar-datos-de-un-recyclerview) en la cuál se me otorgó una respuesta y me funcionó brevemente. El problema es que ya no me estaría funcionando y no entiendo muy bien como solucionarlo. El concepto es: Tengo un Fragment, el cual carga un listado desde `PHP` con `MySQL`:

```
public class ListadoCartuchos extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout linearAlerta;
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> cartuchosArrayList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> arrayList;
    RecyclerViewListaCartuchos adaptador;

    public ListadoCartuchos() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listado, container, false);

        cartuchosArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        alerta = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAlertaCantidadCartuchos);
        linearAlerta = view.findViewById(R.id.linearAlertaCartucho);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCartuchos);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        listadoCartuchos();

        return view;
    }

    public void listadoCartuchos() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url.php",
                response -> {
            Cartuchos cartuchos = new Cartuchos();
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            int id = jsonObject1.getInt("idCartucho");
                            String modelo = jsonObject1.getString("modelo");
                            String color = jsonObject1.getString("color");
                            String fec = jsonObject1.getString("fechaModificacion");
                            int cantidad = jsonObject1.getInt("cantidad");
                            arrayList.add(new Cartuchos(id, modelo, color, fec, cantidad));
                        }
                        adaptador = new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(getActivity(), arrayList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("Listado", "listadoCartuchos: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Desde el `Adaptador`, envío los datos que quiero cambiar abriendo una nueva `Activity` después de hacer **click** sobre un elemento del `RecyclerView`:

```
public class RecyclerViewListaCartuchos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> mValues;
    Context mContext;
    String url = "url.php";

    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(Context context, ArrayList<Cartuchos> values) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.vista_diseno_cartucho, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView idCartucho;
        public TextView modeloColor;
        public TextView tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod;
        public ImageView iv_cartucho_img;
        public View layout;
        Cartuchos item;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            cardView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardViewCartucho);
            idCartucho = v.findViewById(R.id.idCartucho);
            modeloColor = v.findViewById(R.id.tvModeloColorCartucho);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod = v.findViewById(R.id.tvFechaModificacionCartucho);
            iv_cartucho_img = v.findViewById(R.id.ivCartuchoImagen);
        }

        public void setData(Cartuchos item) {
            this.item = item;
            String dato = item.getModelo() + " " + item.getColor() + " - Cantidad: " + item.getCantidad();
            String idC = String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho());
            String fec_us = "Última actualización: " + item.getFechaModificacion();
            idCartucho.setText(idC);
            modeloColor.setText(dato);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod.setText(fec_us);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(ConexionInternet.estaConectado(mContext)){
                Intent abrirEditar = new Intent(mContext, Editar.class);
                Cartuchos cartuchos = new Cartuchos();
                int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();
                abrirEditar.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(itemPosition));
                abrirEditar.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho()));
                abrirEditar.putExtra("cantidad", String.valueOf(item.getCantidad()));
                abrirEditar.putExtra("url", url);
                abrirEditar.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(abrirEditar);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Conéctate a una red.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateItem(Cartuchos item, int position){ //the method that i'm use to update data
        //Update array
        mValues.set(position, item);
        //update item in adapter.
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

Con esto se me abre la actividad y en ella cargo los datos, los actualizo (A la `BD` llega el dato actualizado) pero tras cerrar la actividad el `RecyclerView` no ha actualizado el **item**. Intenté solucionarlo de esta manera pero no funciona:

```
public class Editar extends AppCompatActivity {
    String url;
    private EditText etEditarCantidad;
    private final String mensajeVacio = "No puede estar vacío ni el valor debe ser 0 (cero)";
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> arrayList;
    Cartuchos cartuchos;
    String fechaHoy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar);
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        String idC = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idC);
        String cantidad = getIntent().getStringExtra("cantidad");
        String pos = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
        int position = Integer.parseInt(pos);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        cartuchos = new Cartuchos();

        traerFechaHoy();

        etEditarCantidad = findViewById(R.id.etEditarCantidad);
        etEditarCantidad.setText(cantidad);
        Button btnEditar = findViewById(R.id.btnEditar);

        btnEditar.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString().length() == 0
                    || etEditarCantidad.getText().toString().equals("0")){
                Toast.makeText(Editar.this, mensajeVacio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                try{
                    if(ConexionInternet.estaConectado(Editar.this)){
                        cartuchos.setCantidad(Integer.parseInt(cantidad));
                        cartuchos.setFechaModificacion(fechaHoy);
                        arrayList.add(cartuchos);

                        RecyclerViewListaCartuchos recyclerViewListaCartuchos = new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
                        recyclerViewListaCartuchos.updateItem(cartuchos, position); //when i press the button i call the updateItem in Adapter

                        editarCantidad(id);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Conéctate a una red.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error", "Editar error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void editarCantidad(int id){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString())){
            etEditarCantidad.setError("No puede estar vacío.");
            etEditarCantidad.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        final int cant = Integer.parseInt(etEditarCantidad.getText().toString());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
            try {
                if (response.contains("Error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Lo sentimos, ha ocurrido un error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Modificado con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Editar.this.finish();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, error -> Log.e("onErrorEdit", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage())){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                parametros.put("cantidad", String.valueOf(cant));
                parametros.put("id", String.valueOf(id));
                return parametros;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Editar.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void traerFechaHoy() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url.php",
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            fechaHoy = jsonObject1.getString("now");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("Fecha", "Fecha hoy error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Editar.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

He añadido este bloque a mi Fragment:

```
public ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                Log.i("INTENTO", "onActivityResult() " + result.getResultCode());
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    
                    boolean update = bundle.getBoolean("update");

                    Log.i("INTENTO", "onActivityResult() actualizar? : " + update );

                    if(update){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Actualizado jejox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No actul je", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Y he modificado el método para cargar los datos al Recycler por este:

```
adaptador = new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(getActivity(), arrayList, ListadoCartuchos.this);
```

Modifiqué mi adaptador de la siguiente manera:

```
public class RecyclerViewListaCartuchos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Cartuchos> mValues;
    Context mContext;
    String url = "url";
    int itemPosition;
    ListadoCartuchos listadoCartuchos;

    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos(Context context, ArrayList<Cartuchos> values, ListadoCartuchos listadoCartuchos) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        this.listadoCartuchos = listadoCartuchos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.vista_diseno_cartucho, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder(view, listadoCartuchos);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView idCartucho;
        public TextView modeloColor;
        public TextView tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod;
        public ImageView iv_cartucho_img;
        public View layout;
        Cartuchos item;
        ListadoCartuchos listadoCartuchos;

        public ViewHolder(View v, ListadoCartuchos listadoCartuchos) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            this.listadoCartuchos = listadoCartuchos;

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            cardView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardViewCartucho);
            idCartucho = v.findViewById(R.id.idCartucho);
            modeloColor = v.findViewById(R.id.tvModeloColorCartucho);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod = v.findViewById(R.id.tvFechaModificacionCartucho);
            iv_cartucho_img = v.findViewById(R.id.ivCartuchoImagen);
        }

        public void setData(Cartuchos item) {
            this.item = item;
            String dato = item.getModelo() + " " + item.getColor() + " - Cantidad: " + item.getCantidad();
            String idC = String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho());
            String fec_us = "Última actualización: " + item.getFechaModificacion();
            idCartucho.setText(idC);
            modeloColor.setText(dato);
            tv_fecha_mod_usuario_mod.setText(fec_us);

            if(item.getModelo().contains("73")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sietetresn);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("90")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nueveceron);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("117")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unounosiete);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("195")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unonuevecinco);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("196")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unonueveseis);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("206")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dosceroseis);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("296")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dosnueveseis);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("E2061")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.edosceroseisuno);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("135")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unotrescinco);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("T6644")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertec);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("T6643")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertec);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("T6642")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertec);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("T6641")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertec);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("544")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tcincocuatrocuatro);
            }
            if(item.getModelo().contains("133")){
                iv_cartucho_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.unotrestres);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();
            if(ConexionInternet.estaConectado(mContext)){
                Intent abrirEditar = new Intent(mContext, Editar.class);
                int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();
                abrirEditar.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(itemPosition));
                abrirEditar.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(item.getIdCartucho()));
                abrirEditar.putExtra("cantidad", String.valueOf(item.getCantidad()));
                abrirEditar.putExtra("url", url);
                abrirEditar.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                listadoCartuchos.mStartForResult.launch(abrirEditar);
                //mContext.startActivity(abrirEditar);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Conéctate a una red.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A mi actividad Editar, le he añadido la siguiente variable:

```
private final boolean actualizar = true;
```

Y al método editarCantidad le agregé lo mencionado en la respuesta:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
            try {
                if (response.contains("Error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Lo sentimos, ha ocurrido un error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Modificado con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("update", actualizar);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                    Editar.this.finish();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Update 2:**

A través del método envío los datos modificados al Fragment:

```
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Editar.this, "Modificado con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("update", actualizar);
                intent.putExtra("posicion", Integer.parseInt(position));
                intent.putExtra("cantidad", cant);
                intent.putExtra("fec", fechaHoy);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                Editar.this.finish();
            }
```

Y en el Fragment los recibo así:

```
                Log.i("INTENTO", "onActivityResult() actualizar? : " + update + "\n datos: Posición" + position + " / Cantidad: " + cantidad + " / Fecha hoy: " + fe);

                if(update){
                    adaptador.updateItem(cartuchos, position);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Actualizado jejox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

En esta línea actualizo los datos. Controlando el Log los datos llegan correctos:

```
I/INTENTO: onActivityResult() actualizar? : true
     datos: Posición: 0 / Cantidad: 8 / Fecha hoy: 27-10-2021
```

Lo cual es correcto pero al presionar el botón llega el error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.frabasoft.providusstock.Adaptadores.RecyclerViewListaCartuchos$ViewHolder.setData(RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.java:86)
        at com.frabasoft.providusstock.Adaptadores.RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.java:46)
        at com.frabasoft.providusstock.Adaptadores.RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewListaCartuchos.java:24)
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione? Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Con respecto a el error "boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference" , en alguna parte de tu código estas tratando de usar .equals con una variable que tiene valor null, eso no tiene que ver con el código propuesto como solución..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahora lo que necesitas es abrir desde el listado de un Fragment una Activity y en esta Activity realizar cambios, al cerrarla se detecte en la Activity original que contiene el Fragment si se realizaron cambios o no.

Puedes hacer uso de [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=es-419#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) para iniciar la Activity y por medio de [onActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=es-419#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) en tu Activity detectar que realizaste un cambio en los datos y de esta forma refrescar tu Adapter.

Revisa:  **[Cómo obtener un resultado de una actividad](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=es-419)**

---

Para esto debes agregar primeramente una dependencia en tu `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0-rc01'


}
```

Desde tu `Fragment` registra el Callback:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult() " + result.getResultCode());
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    //Variable que determina si se debe realizar actualización.
                    boolean update = bundle.getBoolean("update");

                    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult() actualizar? : " + update );

                    if(update){
                       //Actualiza.
                    }else{
                       //No actualiza.
                    }


                }
            }
        });
```

e inicia la Activity de esta forma:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
    mStartForResult.launch(intent);
```

Desde la Activity donde realizas los cambios puedes definir una variable boolen para determinar si se debe actualizar o no el adapter la cual será modificada en la Activity y puedes enviar esta información al agregarla en el Intent dentro de `onBackPressed()` que será llamado cuando cierres la Activity

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean actualizar;

   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("update", actualizar);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

   ...
   ...
   ...

}
```

Revisa: [Cómo obtener un resultado de una actividad](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=es-419)

---

Actualización.

La sugerencia es correcta pero en este caso agregaste el Flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) y esto provoca que la Activity (que contiene el Fragment) no sea la que registra el "Callback" para obtener la respuesta, debes eliminar esta línea y obtendrás el valor que indica actualizar los datos.

```
 Intent abrirEditar = new Intent(mContext, Editar.class);
 ...
 ...
 //abrirEditar.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 listadoCartuchos.mStartForResult.launch(abrirEditar);
```

Además de esto, en tu `ActivityResult` al obtener el valor que indica actualizar, llama nuevamente el método para obtener la información actualizada (`listadoCartuchos()`) y usa `adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged()` para actualizar la información:

```
public ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                boolean update = bundle.getBoolean("update");
                Log.i(TAG, "Fragment onActivityResult() actualizar? : " + update );
                if(update){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Actualizado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                    listadoCartuchos(); //* Obtiene nuevamente la información actualizada.
                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged(); //* Actualiza el adapter.
                    
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No actuliza.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

incluso aquí también podrías obtener la posición y actualizar únicamente el elemento en el cual se realizó el cambio mediante:

```
...
...
  listadoCartuchos(); //* Obtiene nuevamente la información actualizada.
  adaptador.notifyItemChanged(position); // * Actualiza elemento en la posición.
...
...
```

muy importante, cada vez que realices la petición de la información, limpia el `Arraylist` donde almacenas los datos ya que de otra forma solo estarás agregando más información en lugar de actualizarla.

```
  public void listadoCartuchos() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://frabasoft.com.ar/pstock/select_listado_cartuchos.php",
                response -> {
                    try {
                        arrayList.clear();//* Limpia Arraylist!
                        ...
                        ...
                          for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                             ...
                             ...
                             arrayList.add(new Cartuchos(id, modelo, color, fec, cantidad)); //Agrega información.
                           }
                        ...
                        ...
                        }
                        ...
                        ...  
    }
```

Realizando lo anterior podrás actualizar tus datos en el `RecyclerView` sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He hecho como mencionas pero no ha funcionado, sigue sin actualizar los datos el RecyclerVIew. He actualizado mi pregunta conforme a tu respuesta

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo revisaste que obtuvieras un valor true al cerrar la Activity? esto es importante ya que indica cuando actualizar y cuando no.

Comment: Cuando presiono un elemento del `RecyclerView` el `Log` devuelve un 0

Comment: Ok, voy a revisar lo que comentas @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: Hola @FranqoBalsamo el problema es el Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK!

Comment: OREO android XD

Comment: Tampoco funciona, sigue quedando con el antiguo valor @Jorgesys

Comment: Cuando actualizas ahora recibes update con valor true no es así? si es true debes actualizar los datos en el Adapter es que lo único que realizas es mostrar un Toast  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Actualizado jejox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: Si utilizo la línea: `adaptador.updateItem(cartuchos, position);` en el `if(update)` eso lanza una excepción `NullPointer` lo cuál no entiendo porque estoy pasando y trayendo la posición del elemento del array de manera correcta. Desde el adaptador lo envío a la actividad Editar y desde Editar lo envío al Fragment a través del método que señalas. Sin mecionar que luego de implementarlo, se cambiaron todos los valores de cantidad @Jorgesys

Comment: Realiza el cambio para actualizar dentro del ActivityResult, revisa la actualización.

Comment: mil gracias, por tu tiempo y la explicación